# Jasmine spyOn: How to make it work when the spyed function reference is passed?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using jasmine to test my javascript, and I'm finding a hard case to spec. I have this function which is being passed directly to the handler:

```
filters.find('#per_page').change(checkList.filter);
```

Now, I'd like to spy on it and see if it's being called when i change that:

```
describe("when I change the number of items per page", function() {
   beforeEach(function() 
      spyOn(checkList, 'filter');
      $('#per_page').val('50').trigger('change'); 
   });
   it("filters the results list", function() {
     expect(checkList.filter).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
});
```

This test fails. Suprisingly, if I change my code above to:

```
filters.find('#per_page').change(function() { checkList.filter(); });
```

it passes. Is there a way to spy on such functions passed or do I have to resort to the anonymous function case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, but to do so events have to be bound after you have added the spies on your function. The reason for this is that spies replace the property with an other function (it doesn't change the function itself). In your case, what happened is that you assigned the original function and when you added the spies you replaced the property without changing the callback that was bound.

If the way your application is made you can't add your spies before doing the events binding, than the only it can work is to use anonymous function which call the proper callback.